# Graph path finder

Tags: java, recursion, graph, nodes

i am trying to find a path in between  two nodes(sourcenode and targetnode). i came up with this code but i cant seem to make it recursively find a path. i even set the nodes to null if the target node is found but i keep getting a stack overflow error.

```
public void findPathBetween(Node sourceNode, Node targetNode){
    //find a path between the sourceNode and targetNode
    //select the nodes and edges along the path if one exists.

    ArrayList<Node> nodesToSearch = new ArrayList<Node>();
    nodesToSearch.add(sourceNode);

    //basis
    if(sourceNode == null || targetNode == null) return;

    //recursion
    ArrayList<Node> newNodesToSearch = new ArrayList<Node>(); //get nodes for next level to search
    for(Node aNode : nodesToSearch) {
        for (Node neighbour : aNode.getNeighbours()) {
            if (neighbour != targetNode && newNodesToSearch.isEmpty()) {
                newNodesToSearch.add(neighbour);
                neighbour.setSelected(true);
                edgeBetween(aNode, neighbour).setSelected(true);
                sourceNode = neighbour;
            }
            if (neighbour == targetNode) {
                sourceNode = null;
                targetNode = null;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if(sourceNode != null &&targetNode != null) {
        findPathBetween(sourceNode, targetNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the state inside the recursion function, and don't pass it to the next iteration. Thus you are simply running one function over and over without changing its arguments and the state that affects its execution.

I do not want to correct your code because I would have to guess you intents in order to provide a good explanation.

Anyway I think that you were trying to implement [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), so I suggest you to take a look at some working implementations. Just google them, there are plenty, e.g. [this one](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41graph/DepthFirstPaths.java.html) comes with a piece of [theory](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41graph/), is simple, and was written by [Robert Sedgewick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sedgewick_%28computer_scientist%29), so it can be trusted.